# How should I represent to-be binary data?

Tags: design, python

I'm writing some serialization code, and I'm wondering how to deal with binary data. As I'm doing it in Python, my goal is to make it very simple, not require a lot of programmer overhead, etc.

Three options I am considering:

1. The fields that will be binary data are represented as hex-encoded strings. Thus you'd have something like:

   ```
   obj = {
      'foo': 100,
      'bar': [1, 2, 3, 4],
      'baz': "ab0123ffbbaa55",
   }

   ObjectSpec.loads(ObjectSpec(obj).dumps())
   ```

   `ObjectSpec` is the class which determines how to serialize the object.

   - The pros: it's easy to look at, easy to make object literals, easy to print out.
   - The cons: you have to remember to hex-encode the fields. If you have bytes, you have to hex-encode them before the serialization code then hex-decodes them. If you want to store the objects, there's more overhead unless you hex-decode the strings first.
2. The fields are byte strings, instead, e.g.:

   ```
   obj = {
      'foo': 100,
      'bar': [1, 2, 3, 4],
      'baz': '\xab\x01#\xff\xbb\xaaU',
   }
   ```

   - The pros: less overhead, both in space, and in not having to hex-encode if you already have bytes.
   - The cons: harder to make literals, harder to print out. If you accidentally leave in a hex-encoded string then it will serialize the wrong thing (the hex representation instead of the thing itself).
3. The binary data fields use some custom type, e.g. `bson.Binary`:

   ```
   from bson import Binary

   obj = {
      'foo': 100,
      'bar': [1, 2, 3, 4],
      'baz': Binary('\xab\x01#\xff\xbb\xaaU'),
   }
   ```

   - The pros: Same as #2, but also clearly delineates binary types.
   - The cons: Same as #2, except harder to accidentally encode the wrong thing. Requires wrapping the data in a type just to get the serialization code to accept it, instead of leaving bytes in.

What would the most sensible approach be? Is there another variant that is better?

Comment: Have you considered [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) ?

Comment: @BenCottrell: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm actually re-implementing some C++ app's custom serialization (yep...), so I can't take that option in this case.

Comment: So you have no way to modify the C++ code for that app?  Protocol Buffers is portable and has bindings in many languages, including C++.

Comment: @BenCottrell: I can indeed change the C++ code. Can I do custom serialization with the protocol buffers though? The serialization has to be backwards-compatible.

Comment: That depends what you mean - protocol buffers is a wire format in itself (which you can't change); so it has serialisation types for int/string/double/etc.  It also allows you to package up any kind of existing arbitrary binary data using `bytes`.   You can create a byte array and wrapper that up inside a protobuf message if you need to preserve the existing format.    However if you can modify the C++ code, then you could create new messages using the bindings (The bindings are auto-generated `class`es using getters/setters for int/bool/std::string/etc. )

Comment: For using protobuf as a `bytes` 'wrapper' in C++, the bindings force you to work with `std::string` (which is a really bizarre choice - I'd have assumed that `std::vector<char>` would be more idiomatic).     Although the underlying representation of std::string has a lot in common with the underlying representation of vector<char> - so it "works" fine, but looks strange.

Answer (score 1):

You can define binary and hexadecimal values in python, just use `0xff` or `0b1001010101001`. They are defined as sub-class of `int`. `chr` and `ord` function reads them very clearly.

```
object = {
   "foo": 100 
   "bar": [1,2,3,4],
   "baz": 0xffaff34441faabc # i realy dont get what foo,bar and baz are so i dont really know what your string should represent.
}
```

And then use binary operators and binary shift left, binary shift right to manage it into a right order. for example sending 13 byte data to someport with imaginary syntax PORT:STOP:MESSAGE : `0xFF00737461636B65786368616E6765`, or send *"stackexchange" to port 255*, where `0xff` is port, `0x00` is STOP, and the rest is message. So your function would be something like this, first 2 bytes are port, if next iz 0x00 then split and the rest "translate" to string.

If you want to test in safe enviorment you can use
`map(chr, [0x73,0x74,0x61,0x63,0x6B,0x65,0x78,0x63,0x68,0x61,0x6E,0x67,0x65])`